Godot4 polygon2d stretches texture
I am trying to add a texture to a polygon2d, when I draw the polygon and it is not pixel perfect, it adds these unwated pixels to the image:

Adding 1 pixel of transparency in each direction around the texture should stop it.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
